# Почему в wordpress не отображается главная страница, хотя я её выбрал как статическую в настройках?

Tags: wordpress

В настройках чтения выбрал статическую страницу как Главную. Редактирую в редакторе страницу, но изменения не отображаются. Главная страница как была так и осталась в виде списка записей и набором виджетов, почему статическая страница не отображается как главная?
Хочу чтобы Главная была как и другие страницы, чтобы я редактировал в обычном редакторе главную страницу.

Comment: кеширование .....

Comment: нет, я выбрал статическую страницу
https://skr.sh/s8Glyqsh4L5?a
вот так я редактирую как обычную страницу, но она не меняется, страницу могу менять только в визуальном редакторе, как мне сделать чтобы изменять Главную страницу в обычном редакторе wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте посмотреть Внешний вид/Настроить/Настройки главной страницы. Там должна быть возможность выбрать что отображать на главной странице, последние записи или статическую страницу. Если выбрать статическую, то появляется возможность указать конкретную страницу.